# What's a good way to define data in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object

I'm used to PHP, where I can easily do something like:

```
$data = array(
  'google' => array('title' => 'Google', 'url' => 'http://google.com'),
  'facebook' => array('title' => 'Facebook', 'url' => 'http://facebook.com'),
  'youtube' => array('title' => 'YouTube', 'url' => 'http://youtube.com')
);
```

What's a similar way to create an array or object of data using Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for object literals:

```
var data = {
    google: { title: "Google", url: "http://google.com" },
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var data = {
    'google': {
        'title': 'Google',
        'url': 'http://google.com'
    },
    'facebook': {
         // etc
    }
    // etc
};
```

Answer (score 3):

@Slaks already give you the literals, I'll give an alternative:

```
var data = new Object;

data['google'] = new Object;
data['google']['title'] = 'Google Site';
.
.
.
```